# NativeScript and serialport?

Tags: javascript, android, serial-port, nativescript

Please tell me how you can use serial-port in nativescript. I found a library for  [React-Native](https://github.com/mapaiva/react-native-usbserial), maybe there is something similar for NativeScript. Thank.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) 
to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a plugin at the moment. You may write one or access the [native android library](https://github.com/mapaiva/react-native-usbserial) directly in your {N} project.

Learn more about marshalling [Java into JS here](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/marshalling/java-to-js).